# How to use this PHP code in a shortcode for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

How can I use the following code in a WordPress shortcode?

```
//Variables
$DesdeLetra = "a";
$HastaLetra = "z";
$DesdeNumero = 1;
$HastaNumero = 10000;

$letraAleatoria = chr(rand(ord($DesdeLetra), ord($HastaLetra)));
$numeroAleatorio = rand($DesdeNumero, $HastaNumero);

echo "<strong>La letra aleatoria generada en PHP es:</strong> ".$letraAleatoria."<br/>";
echo "<strong>El número aleatorio generado en PHP es:</strong> ".$numeroAleatorio."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the code works, you can try this:

```
add_shortcode( 'yourshortcode', 'so61578297_custom_shortcode' );
function so61578297_custom_shortcode() {

  $DesdeLetra = "a";
  $HastaLetra = "z";
  $DesdeNumero = 1;
  $HastaNumero = 10000;

  $letraAleatoria = chr(rand(ord($DesdeLetra), ord($HastaLetra)));
  $numeroAleatorio = rand($DesdeNumero, $HastaNumero);

  $r = "<strong>La letra aleatoria generada en PHP es:</strong> ".$letraAleatoria."<br/>";
  $r .= "<strong>El número aleatorio generado en PHP es:</strong> ".$numeroAleatorio."<br/>";

  return $r;

}
```

Past this snippet in your theme's functions.php file, then you can use the shortcode in the WP editor:

```
[yourshortcode]
```

As you are generating random letters/numbers, be sure to not have any caching active on that page.

Good luck!

Comment: why not concatenate both $r ? We could have used it like this $r = "<strong>La letra aleatoria generada en PHP es:</strong> ".$letraAleatoria."<br/>"."<strong>El número aleatorio generado en PHP es:</strong> ".$numeroAleatorio."<br/>";

Comment: Yeah, that's also a possibility. I wanted to keep his code similar to the original one :)